# Any web services which provide financial statements?

Tags: web-services, financial

Basically, I am looking for three financial statements data in machine readable format: balance sheet, income statement and statement of cash flows.[XigniteFinancials](http://www.xignite.com/xFinancials.asmx) is one such provider but I couldn't find any other. Also, XigniteFinancials don't cover UK companies which would have been nice.

Does anybody know of any alternatives to Xignite?

Answer (score 3):

http://www.xignite.com/xFinancials.asmx

Comment: That is already mentioned in the question. Another one I have just come across is Mergent Company Fundamentals API (http://www.mergent.com/servius/) but it is more costly than Xignite.